# Nested class returns 'undefined reference to' when accesing variables from upper class

Tags: c++

I am working on a card game simulator and when I access a variable from an upper class the compiler shows an "undefined reference to" error.  Does any know a solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>


class Game{
    public:
    static std::vector<int> usableDeck;

  private:



class Player {   

    public:   
        void pickCard() {
            usableDeck.push_back(0);
        }
};

public:
   void startGame() {
    Player player;
    player.pickCard();
}
};


int main() {
  Game game{};
  game.startGame();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nested classes in C++ are purely a trick of namespaces. The *only* relationship between your `Game` and `Game::Player` classes is that the names happen to look similar. Neither retains references to the other in instances.

Comment: Why are you using nested classes?  IMHO, one class per file, not nested, allows for easier use and reuse.  You don't get issues like this one.

Comment: The code *declares* `usableDeck`, but it doesn't define it anywhere.  Change it to `static inline std::vector<int> usableDeck;` which will *declare* and *define* it.  Change `pickCard` code to call it by `Game::usableDeck.push_back(0);`.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
static vector<int> usableDeck;
```

is just a declaration.
Initialize it outside the class definition with something like

```
std::vector<int> Game::usableDeck = {};
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/4exjv9jca

Answer (score -1):

Nested classes don't work the way you think. In particular, from `Player` within `Game`, you cannot access a member (e.g. `usableDeck`) of `Game` without an instance of `Game`. To make it work, you might either pass an instance of `Game` to `pickCard()` or store a reference to `Game&` in `Player`.

Edit: as pointed out, it's static. For a static, you might still use the above - or, simpler, you might apply the scope, `Game::usableDeck`.

Comment: usableDeck is static. No instance is needed, just a scope. I,e, `Game::usableDeck`